# how to read all 1's in an Array of 1's and 0's spread-ed all over the array randomly

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have an Array with 1 and 0 spread over the array randomly.

```
int arr[N] = {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1....................N}
```

Now I want to retrive all the 1's in the array as fast as possible, but the condition is I should not loose the exact position(based on index) of the array , so sorting option not valid.
So the only option left is linear searching ie O(n) , is there anything better than this.

> The main problem behind linear scan is , I need to run the scan even
>   for X times. So I feel I need to have some kind of other datastructure
>   which maintains this list once the first linear scan happens, so that
>   I need not to run the linear scan again and again.

```
Let me be clear about final expectations-
```

*I just need to find the number of 1's in a certain range of array , precisely I need to find numbers of 1's in the array within range of 40-100. So this can be random range and I need to find the counts of 1 within that range. I can't do sum and all as I need to iterate over the array over and over again because of different range requirements*

Comment: Atleast a linear scan is required since array is randomly distributed. Will be shocked if anything better than O(N) exists.

Comment: The linear scan is lower complexity than a sort anyway (O(N) instead of minimum of O(N log N) for a sort).

Comment: As a side note. Besides being your only option in this case, linear scans are sometimes faster than algorithms that require random access such as binary search. This is due to the caching that modern computers use.

Comment: This question is not clear. if you just wanted to get # of 1s and 0s. Just sum over array. And the result is # of 1s. Then (size - result) is # of 0s.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? If you want to find the sum from index i to index j, then there are data structure that allows you do make many such query quickly.

Comment: Binary Indexed Tree is usable for this, since the problem is basically range sum query. You construct the data structure in O(n log n) and make a query in O(log n) time. However, I don't know how well it performs against linear scan, since the memory usage to maintain the Binary Indexed Tree (still O(n)) has constant factor bigger than the memory usage to store the array of bits. (More memory, more cache miss)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question, bunta.  In addition to my answer about branch prediction, I've showed how you can use dynamic programming to do your queries in O(1) time after an initial O(N) pass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm surprised you considered sorting as a faster alternative to linear search.

If you don't know where the ones occur, then there is no better way than linear searching.  Perhaps if you used bits or `char` datatypes you could do some optimizations, but it depends on how you want to use this.

The best optimization that you could do on this is to overcome branch prediction.  Because each value is zero or one, you can use it to advance the index of the array that is used to store the one-indices.

Simple approach:

```
int end = 0;
int indices[N];

for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    if( arr[i] ) indices[end++] = i;  // Slow due to branch prediction
}
```

Without branching:

```
int end = 0;
int indices[N];

for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    indices[end] = i;
    end += arr[i];
}
```

---

**[edit]** I tested the above, and found the version without branching was almost 3 times faster (4.36s versus 11.88s for 20 repeats on a randomly populated 100-million element array).

Coming back here to post results, I see you have updated your requirements.  What you want is really easy with a dynamic programming approach...

All you do is create a new array that is one element larger, which stores the number of ones from the beginning of the array up to (but not including) the current index.

```
arr   :   1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
count : 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 6 6 6 7
```

(I've offset `arr` above so it lines up better)

Now you can compute the number of 1s in any range in O(1) time.  To compute the number of 1s between index `A` and `B`, you just do:

```
int num = count[B+1] - count[A];
```

Obviously you can still use the non-branch-prediction version to generate the counts initially.  All this should give you a pretty good speedup over the naive approach of summing for every query:

```
int *count = new int[N+1];
int total = 0;

count[0] = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    total += arr[i];
    count[i+1] = total;
}


// to compute the ranged sum:
int range_sum( int *count, int a, int b )
{
    if( b < a ) return range_sum(b,a);
    return count[b+1] - count[a];
}
```

Comment: This works for static data. I don't know whether OP's data is static or not, but it is indeed the best solution for static data.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  The OP seemed to indicate that the array contents would not change.  Either way, I quite like the branch-prediction test results.  Branch prediction is something I learned about by absorbing material on StackOverflow, so it's nice to actually give it back.

Answer (score 3):

Well one time linear scanning is fine. Since you are looking for multiple scans across ranges of array I think that can be done in constant time. Here you go:

1. Scan the array and create a bitmap where key = key of array = sequence (1,2,3,4,5,6....).The value storedin bitmap would be a `tuple<IsOne,cumulativeSum>` where isOne is whether you have a one in there and cumulative Sum is addition of 1's as and wen you encounter them

   Array = 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0

   Tuple: (1,1) (1,2) (0,2) (0,2) (1,3) (0,3) (1,4) (1,5) (1,6) (0,6)  (1,7)  (0,7)
2. CASE 1: When lower bound of cumulativeSum has a 0. Number of 1's [6,11] =
   cumulativeSum at 11th position - cumulativeSum at 6th position = 7 - 3 = 4

   CASE 2: When lower bound of cumulativeSum has a 1. Number of 1's [2,11] =
   cumulativeSum at 11th position - cumulativeSum at 2nd position + 1 = 7-2+1 = 6

Step 1 is O(n)

Step 2 is 0(1)

Total complexity is linear no doubt but for your task where you have to work with the ranges several times the above Algorithm seems to be better if you have ample memory :)

Comment: Wow thats what I call memoization.

Comment: This seems to be very similar to @paddy's answer, which implies that it isn't really necessary to store the first term in each of the tuples because that term can be calculated if necessary from the difference between one cumulative sum and the next.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a simple linear array data structure?  Or can you create your own data structure which happens to have the desired properties, for which you're able to provide the required API, but whose implementation details can be hidden (encapsulated)?

If you can implement your own and if there is some guaranteed sparsity (to either 1s or 0s) then you might be able to offer better than linear performance.  I see that you want to preserve (or be able to regenerate) the exact stream, so you'll have to store an array or bitmap or run-length encoding for that.  (RLE will be useless if the stream is actually *random* rather than arbitrary but could be quite useful if there are significant sparsity or patterns with long strings of one or the other.  For example a black&white raster of a bitmapped image is often a good candidate for RLE).

Let's say that your guaranteed that the stream will be sparse --- that no more than 10%, for example, of the bits will be 1s (or, conversely that more than 90% will be).  If that's the case then you might model your solution on an RLE and maintain a count of all 1s (simply incremented as you set bits and decremented as you clear them).  If there might be a need to quickly get the number of set bits for arbitrary ranges of these elements then instead of a single counter you can have a conveniently sized array of counters for partitions of the stream.  (Conveniently-sized, in this case, means something which fits easily within memory, within your caches, or register sets, but which offers a reasonable trade off between computing a sum (all the partitions fully within the range) and the linear scan.  The results for any arbitrary range is the sum of all the partitions fully enclosed by the range plus the results of linear scans for any fragments that are not aligned on your partition boundaries.

For a very, very, large stream you could even have a multi-tier "index" of partition sums --- traversing from the largest (most coarse) granularity down toward the "fragments" to either end (using the next layer of partition sums) and finishing with the linear search of only the small fragments.

Obviously such a structure represents trade offs between the complexity of building and maintaining the structure (inserting requires additional operations and, for an RLE, might be very expensive for anything other than appending/prepending) vs the expense of performing arbitrarily long linear search/increment scans.

Comment: +1: The RLE approach could represent a very substantial saving of storage for very sparse cases, as well as speeding up recounts.

Comment: Technically the savings don't depend on the sparsity (ratio of one type of element to another) but rather on the frequency of changes.  A silhouette bitmap image, for example, might consist of only one or two state changes per line (raster) and thus will encode into something like three or four elements per raster line.  This is true even if the ratio of foreground to background is close to 50%

Answer (score 0):

If:

1. the purpose is to be able to find the number of 1s in the array at any time,
2. given that relatively few of the values in the array might change between one moment when you want to know the number and another moment, and
3. if you have to find the number of 1s in a changing array of `n` values `m` times,

... you can certainly do better than examining every cell in the array `m` times by using a caching strategy.

The first time you need the number of 1s, you certainly have to examine every cell, as others have pointed out. However, if you then store the number of 1s in a variable (say `sum`) and track changes to the array (by, for instance, requiring that all array updates occur through a specific `update()` function), every time a `0` is replaced in the array with a `1`, the `update()` function can add `1` to `sum` and every time a `1` is replaced in the array with a `0`, the `update()` function can subtract `1` from `sum`.

Thus, `sum` is always up-to-date after the first time that the number of 1s in the array is counted and there is no need for further counting.

(EDIT to take the updated question into account)

If the need is to return the number of 1s in a given range of the array, that can be done with a slightly more sophisticated caching strategy than the one I've just described.

You can keep a count of the 1s in each subset of the array and update the relevant subset count whenever a 0 is changed to a 1 or vice versa within that subset. Finding the total number of 1s in a given range within the array would then be a matter of adding the number of 1s in each subset that is fully contained within the range and then counting the number of 1s that are in the range but not in the subsets that have already been counted.

Depending on circumstances, it might be worthwhile to have a hierarchical arrangement in which (say) the number of 1s in the whole array is at the top of the hierarchy, the number of 1s in each `1/q th` of the array is in the second level of the hierarchy, the number of 1s in each `1/(q^2) th` of the array is in the third level of the hierarchy, etc. e.g. for `q = 4`, you would have the total number of 1s at the top, the number of 1s in each quarter of the array at the second level, the number of 1s in each sixteenth of the array at the third level, etc.

Comment: What you described in the second half is similar to segment tree.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using C (or derived language)? If so, can you control the encoding of your array? If, for example, you could use a bitmap to count. The nice thing about a bitmap, is that you can use a lookup table to sum the counts, though if your subrange ends aren't divisible by 8, you'll have to deal with end partial bytes specially, but the speedup will be significant.

If that's not the case, can you at least encode them as single bytes? In that case, you may be able to exploit sparseness if it exists (more specifically, the hope that there are often multi index swaths of zeros).

So for:

```
u8 input = {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1....................N};
```

You can write something like (untested):

```
uint countBytesBy1FromTo(u8 *input, uint start, uint stop)
{ // function for counting one byte at a time, use with range of less than 4,
  // use functions below for longer ranges
  // assume it's just one's and zeros, otherwise we have to test/branch
    uint sum;
    u8 *end = input + stop;
    for (u8 *each = input + start; each < end; each++)
        sum += *each; 
    return sum;
}

countBytesBy8FromTo(u8 *input, uint start, uint stop)
{
    u64 *chunks = (u64*)(input+start);
    u64 *end = chunks + ((start - stop) >> 3);
    uint sum = countBytesBy1FromTo((u8*)end, 0, stop - (u8*)end);
    for (; chunks < end; chunks++)
    {
        if (*chunks)
        {
            sum += countBytesBy1FromTo((u8*)chunks, 0, 8);
        }
    }
}
```

The basic trick, is exploiting the ability to cast slices of your target array to single entities your language can look at in one swoop, and test by inference if ANY of the values of it are zeros, and then skip the whole block. The more zeros, the better it will work. In the case where your large cast integer always has at least one, this approach just adds overhead. You might find that using a u32 is better for your data. Or that adding a u32 test between the 1 and 8 helps. For datasets where zeros are much more common than ones, I've used this technique to great advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Why is sorting invalid? You can clone the original array, sort the clone, and count and/or mark the locations of the `1`s as needed.